# Ruby IO.readlines stops before the last line of a file

Tags: ruby, readlines

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on a Windows machine.

When I run `IO.readlines` on a file, I get an odd and unexpected result.  The result of running `IO.readlines` on a file is an array that just ends in a line that isn't the last line in the file.  For example, the last element in the array is this string:

```
MLOGIC(RESPONSE_FREQUENCY):  Parameter NUMERATOR_SUBSET has value \x01where
```

This is the last element in the array even though the file actually has many more lines.

When I run `IO.readlines` on the exact same file on OS X using Ruby 2.0.0, there is no issue; it reads the whole file into an array as expected.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference of `IO.readlines` (docs [1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-readlines) and [2.0.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines)) on Windows vs. OSX is the default line seperator `$/`—on unixoid system you'll find that to be `"\n"` and on Windows it is `"\r\n"`.

To get the same behaviour, you can call `IO.readlines` like so:

```
arr = IO.readlines('./testfile', "\n")
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your response.I tried that, but it did not change the result.  The result of IO.readlines is still smaller than it should be.  I think there's a hex character in the file.  I think IO.readlines stops when it gets to that character.

Comment: Well, it *should* not. Did you try a `File.read('./testfile').split("\n")`?

Comment: I just tried the code with split.  Same result.  It stops when it hits a character that seems like a hex character to me.

Comment: Yes.  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5745ee1462f4dc584ba1  In the text file that I see on my machine, there's a character that my text editor displays as a right-pointing arrow. It's just before the 3 at the end of the fourth line.  It does not come through in the gist, though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will have look into that later in the evening (I'm in UTC+1).

Comment: I found some code that does work:  file = File.open(filename, 'rb') { |f| f.read }.split("\r\n").  It's significantly slower, though.